# nodejs oracle-db multiple DB connection

Tags: node.js, node-oracledb

I wanted to create two database connection and periodically check the status of database connection. If database 1 fails I want to switch the connection to database 2. Can you give me some pointers please?

Answer (score 0):

The first question is what exactly are you trying to do during the 'failover'.  Is the Node.js app doing some work for users, or is it just the monitoring script?  Then, next is how are your DBs configured (I'm guessing it's not RAC)?

There are all sorts of '[high availability](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/clustering/applicationcontinuity/adb-continuousavailability-5169724.pdf)' options and levels in Oracle, many of which are transparent to the application and are available when you use a connection pool.  A few are described in the node-oracledb doc - look at [Connections and High Availability](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionha).  Other things can be configured in a `tnsnames.ora` file such as connection retries if connection requests fail.

As the most basic level the answer to your question is that you could periodically check whether a query works, or just use [`connection.ping()`](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionping).  If you go this 'roll your own' route, use a connection pool with size 1 for each DB.  Then periodically get the connection from the pool and use it.

If you update your question with details, it would be easier to answer.